# Retreive data from firebase database on button click and these data display in other actvity in list format

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
   Button ten, twelve;
    ten=(Button) findViewById(R.id.tenth) ;
    twelve=(Button) findViewById(R.id.twelth) ;
    ten.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Customer_details");



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

my class

package com.example.shikshaMela.sm;

public class course_tenth {

```
    String name = "";
    String college_list = "";

    String fee = "";
    String duration = "";
    String higher_study = "";
    String job_aspects = "";
    String entrance_exam = "";





public course_tenth() {

}

public course_tenth(String name, String college_list, String fee, String duration, String higher_study, String job_aspects, String entrance_exam)
    {


        this.name = name;
        this.college_list = college_list;

        this.fee = fee;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.higher_study = higher_study;
        this.job_aspects = job_aspects;
        this.entrance_exam = entrance_exam;
    }

public String getname() {
    return name;
}

public String getCollege_list() {
    return college_list;
}



public String getFee() {
    return fee;
}

public String getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public String getHigher_study() {
    return higher_study;
}

public String getJob_aspects() {
    return job_aspects;
}

public String getEntrance_exam() {
    return entrance_exam;
}
```

}

}
`i want to fetch the all list of courses(like bca ) from database and it display in list in other activity. these items(bca) are clickable so, when we click on these items(bca) then its internal data(like college eligibility etc. are fetched).

How can I do that?

[my firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KtBO.png)

Comment: create model class and store the result is arraylist of model type,when you click any item just pass the item from the arraylist.

Comment: i create class but i confused is it right or not or when we want to store the data in array list, so many error are come, if you give the process the store the data in array list and pass item from the array list then i thakful

Answer (score 0):

```
 // refer --> your DatabaseReference
 refer.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Iterator<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshotsChat = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

            User user = null; // User is Model class
            while (dataSnapshotsChat.hasNext()) {
                DataSnapshot dataSnapshotChild = dataSnapshotsChat.next();
                user = dataSnapshotChild.getValue(User.class);

                if (!Lists.contains(user.id)) { // here List is array list of type User
                    Lists.add(user);
                }
       }
```

});

Comment: ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  Iterator<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshotsChat=dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
Course_details course = null;
            while (dataSnapshotsChat.hasNext()) {
                DataSnapshot dataSnapshotChild = dataSnapshotscourse_tenth.next();
                Course_details = dataSnapshotChild.getValue(Course_details.class);
  if (!Lists.contains(Course_details.course_tenth)) { 
                    Lists.add(Course_details);
                }
       }

Comment: it is not work so many error shows, import the iterator, arraylist,valueevent listener class

Comment: just import the class.

Comment: and also send your ref

Comment: i dont know what you want to say

Comment: DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Customer_details")   , does "Customer_details" node is available in ur db.

Comment: error show in valueeventlistener, datasnapshot, lists,addlistenerforsinglevalue event

Comment: import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

Comment: you cant  able to import class ValueEventListener ?

Comment: still is show error even after importing those class ?

Comment: what error your are getting...?have u configured your gradle with firebase properly ?

Comment: red line show in  View.OnClickListener(), ValueEventListener,and red written in dataSnapshot,lists